# How to write own DD() function same as laravel?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, var-dump

I used laravel for a long time but currently I work with wordpress. I loved using the laravel's `DD()` function.
But in wordpress I can only use these,

```
   print_r(),
   var_dump(),
   var_export()....
```

These all are just expand entire **array** or **object**.
But I need laravel's **expand** and **close** mechanism for handling array and object.
I use the following as general **dd** need,

```
if (!function_exists('dd')) {
 function dd()
  {
      echo '<pre>';
      array_map(function($x) {var_dump($x);}, func_get_args());
      die;
   }
 }
```

It works well, but I need a styled and organised form of listing.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/var-dumper

Comment: @RajenderJoshi Sometimes you want a rubber tire instead of one made from wood or stone. Laravel uses varDumper only for the formatting - the behaviour is _kind of_ different, because the execution is not stopped after dumping data.

Comment: @RajenderJoshi in my case, i need dd() as a static file, not as a Composer package, as the legacy application would otherwise break (as it would call autoloader several times)

Answer (score 42):

Laravel's `dd` uses symfony's [VarDump component](https://github.com/symfony/var-dumper). It provides a globally available `dump` function which formats the output. The only difference is that it won`t "die" after the dump, you'll have to do that manually - but in most cases that isn't even something you'd want.

1. Run `composer global require symfony/var-dumper` (assuming you have composer in your wordpress project)
2. Add `auto_prepend_file = ${HOME}/.composer/vendor/autoload.php` to your php.ini file;
3. From time to time, run `composer global update symfony/var-dumper` to have the latest bug fixes.

Here is the documentation for the VarDumper component. https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html

**symfony/var-dumper version >= 4.1:**

Since var-dumper version 4.1, `dd()` is already declared. Loading the library is enough.

---

**symfony/var-dumper version <= 4.0:**

Declare a `dd` function, dumping all arguments and stopping the process:

```
if (!function_exists('dd')) {
    function dd()
    {
        foreach (func_get_args() as $x) {
            dump($x);
        }
        die;
    }
 }
```

Comment: latest VarDumper versions already have dd function added by default. You don't have to manually create one.

Answer (score 23):

I updated more functions and latest code of `d` functions below in [debug functions](https://github.com/mlightvn/debug-functions) package.

(Below answer is about 1 year ago.)

======================================

Below is my own code. It can work in plain PHP (no framework).

```
function d($data){
    if(is_null($data)){
        $str = "<i>NULL</i>";
    }elseif($data == ""){
        $str = "<i>Empty</i>";
    }elseif(is_array($data)){
        if(count($data) == 0){
            $str = "<i>Empty array.</i>";
        }else{
            $str = "<table style=\"border-bottom:0px solid #000;\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">";
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $str .= "<tr><td style=\"background-color:#008B8B; color:#FFF;border:1px solid #000;\">" . $key . "</td><td style=\"border:1px solid #000;\">" . d($value) . "</td></tr>";
            }
            $str .= "</table>";
        }
    }elseif(is_resource($data)){
        while($arr = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
            $data_array[] = $arr;
        }
        $str = d($data_array);
    }elseif(is_object($data)){
        $str = d(get_object_vars($data));
    }elseif(is_bool($data)){
        $str = "<i>" . ($data ? "True" : "False") . "</i>";
    }else{
        $str = $data;
        $str = preg_replace("/\n/", "<br>\n", $str);
    }
    return $str;
}

function dnl($data){
    echo d($data) . "<br>\n";
}

function dd($data){
    echo dnl($data);
    exit;
}

function ddt($message = ""){
    echo "[" . date("Y/m/d H:i:s") . "]" . $message . "<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For others who might be interested in Laravel like dd(), please check this repo -

https://github.com/wanfeiyy/laravel-dd

Comment: If you watch the source code of that library, turns out it's actually quite simple to replicate using the original Symphony components. All the logic seems to be in this file and it's quite simple to copy: https://github.com/wanfeiyy/laravel-dd/blob/master/src/Dd/Dumper.php

Answer (score 5):

The Laravel `dd` is actually a great function. However, the undergoing mechanism is `var_dump` and then `die`.

Example:

```
$arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
var_dump($arr);
die();
```

Comment: Yah, you are right. But what abt its schema. It won't elaborate entire array. Because in some cases, array may be too big. In that case we couldn't use that. But laravel do some stuff to minimise this issue by fold up.

Comment: you can set the depth that `var_dump()` will go to. I can't remember how (I think it might be in php.ini)

Answer (score 5):

> composer require --dev symfony/var-dumper

```
<?php     
if (! function_exists('dd')) {
            /**
             * Dump the passed variables and end the script.
             *
             * @param  mixed
             * @return void
             */
            function dd()
            {
                array_map(function ($value) {
                    if (class_exists(Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Dumper\CliDumper::class)) {
                        $dumper = 'cli' === PHP_SAPI ?
                            new Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Dumper\CliDumper :
                            new Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Dumper\HtmlDumper;
                        $dumper->dump((new Symfony\Component\VarDumper\Cloner\VarCloner)->cloneVar($value));
                    } else {
                        var_dump($value);
                    }
                }, func_get_args());
                die(1);
            }
        }

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can bring in this namespace in your class `use Illuminate\Support\Debug\Dumper;` and then use it for your variables like this:

```
(new Dumper)->dump($myVariable);
```

Answer (score 3):

it works like a charm.

```
function dd()
{
   array_map(function($x) { var_dump($x); }, func_get_args()); die;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I do it like this:

```
function dd($a){
    var_dump($a);
    exit;
}
```

I use it all the time. Even created a Snippet for it in Sublime.

I also use [var_masterpiece](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/varmasterpiece/chfhddogiigmfpkcmgfpolalagdcamkl) Chrome extension to get a nice output, where I can expand and collapse the array keys, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I do like this:

```
function dd($var){ 
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($var);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I have a similar function, I would just modify this slightly into echo '<pre>'.print_r($var,true).'</pre>'; exit;

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time i work with laravel framework, when it came to debugging the `dd()` helper method become a very handful tool.

But recently i was requested to work on a symfony 3.4 project, at first i use `dump($my_vars); die();` to dump and die my vars. But that became quickly very combersome. So i ended up by adding a **dd()** global helper method to the symfony 3.4 project, here is how:

Inside `src/` folder i created `Support/` folder, inside of the `Support/` folder i created `helpers.php` file where i added my dump helper functions.

***src/Support/helpers.php***

```
if (!function_exists('dd')) {

    /**
     * Dump the passed variables and end the script.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    function dd() {

        $args = func_get_args();

        call_user_func_array('dump', $args);

        die(1);
    }
}
```

You may need to add the new file (`helpers.php`) to your `composer.json` file to be loaded for you automatically, like this:

***composer.json***

```
{
    ...

    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        },
        "files": [
            "src/Support/helpers.php"
        ]
    },

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The @coloured-panda answer is not working anymore. Here is the updated code:

```
use Symfony\Component\VarDumper\VarDumper;

if (! function_exists('dd')) {
    /**
     * Dump the passed variables and end the script.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $vars
     * @return void
     */
    function dd(...$vars)
    {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
        http_response_code(500);

        foreach ($vars as $v) {
            VarDumper::dump($v);
        }

        die(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the package [mp091689/dump-die](https://packagist.org/packages/mp091689/dump-die) and then you can do:

```
dd($variable);
```

OR

```
dd($variable1, $variable2, ..);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest solution:

```
if(!function_exists('dd'))
{
    function dd( $result )
    {
        echo '<pre>'; print_r($result); die();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!function_exists('dd')) { 
    function dd($arrayData, $exit=TRUE) {
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($arrayData);
        if($exit===TRUE) die();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!function_exists('dd')) {

    #[NoReturn] function dd(mixed $data):void
    {
        echo "<pre style='background:#1d1d1d; color: greenyellow; position:absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 9999999; width: 100%; height: 600px'>";
        print_r($data);
        echo '<pre>';
        die();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following one. Learned from Jeffrey Way:

```
function dd($data)
{
    echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($data);
    echo "</pre>";

    die();
}
```